# SQL Server Audits

Tags: sql-server

im trying to setup a GDPR-Compliant auditing system for our Databases in order to log reading or DML operations in certain tables.

I've read the MS documentation about SQL Auditing and actually didnt found anything helpful about my problem, which comes when queries or data requests come from application users.

**If i run a select on dbo.DevContent1 (even with SA or using my own login) it is recorded,
but If the same query runs in application code, nothing new appears in SQL Audit logs**

Here is my current Audit specifications configuration:

```
USE [MY_DEV_DB]
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [GDPR_DEV_Audits]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [GDPR_PDATA_Audit]
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevContent1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (INSERT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevContent1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevContent1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevContent1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevCustomer1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (INSERT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevCustomer1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevCustomer1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevCustomer1] BY [dbo]),
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevQuotes] BY [dbo]),
ADD (INSERT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevQuotes] BY [dbo]),
ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevQuotes] BY [dbo]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevQuotes] BY [dbo]),
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevUsers] BY [dbo]),
ADD (INSERT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevUsers] BY [dbo]),
ADD (SELECT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevUsers] BY [dbo]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevUsers] BY [dbo])
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

Any idea about how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: What user is your application using to connect to SQL Server? IF it's dbo, please change that (dbo most likely is far more permissions than the application needs). If it's a different user, you need to add audit rules for that user, too.

Comment: Your audit is has `BY [dbo]`. I doubt your applcation is a dbo on the database; and hence why the audit isn't working on the application user.

Comment: well ofcourse it isnt on dbo. But, should i add a custom rule for each DB user used by applications (there are several, web, mobile each one with its user) ? It's going to be a harakiri for me

Comment: I've never worked with audits, however, i *believe* that if you change `[dbo]` to `[public]` it'll work; as every user *should* be a member of the `[public]` role.

Comment: the `[public]` hint seems solving the problem. It is covering almost all users, thanks @Larnu. Feel free to post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the audit isn't working for your application user, is because the Audit has been set up specifically for the user `[dbo]`:

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [GDPR_DEV_Audits]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [GDPR_PDATA_Audit]
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevContent1] BY [dbo]);
```

I doubt that your applicaiton login maps to the user `[dbo]`; as `[dbo]`is the database owner (and thus would have very elevated permissions).

I believe if you want to audit all users on the database you need to use `BY [public]`, as every user *should* be a member of this role. Thus:

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [GDPR_DEV_Audits]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [GDPR_PDATA_Audit]
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[DevContent1] BY [public]);
```

If you do have any users not a member of public, you'll need to add those users (or the roles) separately; or add them to the public role again.